# Adding values from List<T> to database column

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, list

Currently, I can insert a record which contains the `second`, `minute`, `hour`, `Repeat`, `JobId` and `UserID`, however, it will only insert one value from each of the `List<object>`.

Question 1:
How do I add values from a `List<object>` (`model.DayOfMonth`, `model.Month` and `model.DaysOfWeek`) into the local database?

Question 2:
Also, to my understanding, each value in the list should have their own record. How would I create a new record for each value in the `List<object>` (named above) while copying over the same `second`, `minute`, `hour`, `repeat`, `JobId` and `UserID`.

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ScheduleInfo(Values model, int JobList1, string Second, string Minute, string Hour, object DayOfMonth, object Month, object DaysOfWeek, int repeatTime)
    {
        var secondCon = Convert.ToInt32(Second);
        var minuteCon = Convert.ToInt32(Minute);
        var hourCon = Convert.ToInt32(Hour);


        model.Job = JobList1;



        model.Second = secondCon;
        model.Minute = minuteCon;
        model.Hour = hourCon;
        model.DayOfMonth = new List<object>();
        model.Month= new List<object>();
        model.DaysOfWeek = new List<object>();



        foreach (var dofm in model.DofMInfo)
        {
            if (dofm.IsChecked)
            {
                model.DayOfMonth.Add(dofm.DofMID);
            }
        }

        foreach (var month in model.MonthInfo)
        {
            if (month.IsChecked)
            {
                model.Month.Add(month.monthID);
            }
        }

        foreach (var day in model.DayInfo)
        {
            if (day.IsChecked)
            {
                model.DaysOfWeek.Add(day.dayID);
            }
        }

        model.repeatTime = repeatTime;

        try
        {
            ScheduleEntity db = new ScheduleEntity();

            AspNetUser aspNetUser = new AspNetUser();
            Job job = new Job();

            Schedule sched = new Schedule();

            sched.Second = Convert.ToString(model.Second);
            sched.Minute = Convert.ToString(model.Minute);
            sched.Hour = Convert.ToString(model.Hour);


            //foreach (var day in model.DayOfMonth)
            //{
            //    sched.DayOfMonth = Convert.ToString(day);
            //}


            //foreach (var month in model.Month)
            //{
            //    sched.Month = Convert.ToString(month);
            //}


            //foreach (var weekday in model.DaysOfWeek)
            //{
            //    sched.DayOfWeek = Convert.ToString(weekday);
            //}


            sched.Repeat = 4;
            sched.JobId = 2;
            sched.AspNetUsersId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
            db.Schedules.Add(sched);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }


        return RedirectToAction("SchedulerIndex");
    }
}
```

The Schedule class I'm calling and setting as `sched`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public partial class Schedule
{
    public int ScheduleID { get; set; }
    public string Second { get; set; }
    public string Minute { get; set; }
    public string Hour { get; set; }
    public string DayOfMonth { get; set; }
    public string Month { get; set; }
    public string DayOfWeek { get; set; }
    public string AspNetUsersId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> JobId { get; set; }
    public int Repeat { get; set; }

    public virtual AspNetUser AspNetUser { get; set; }
    public virtual Job Job { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: why List<object>? Why not List<int>?

Comment: Make use of JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize & JavaScriptSerializer.Serialize. Here when you get all values inside save model i.e DayOfMonth, Month and DaysOfWeek then serialized them and inside the database save it in single cell as a string Value which is actually your json string. And when you want to use it , get the values from db first the column values are return in form of string and you can deserialized them and can store it back in List<int>.I think this is the best and easiest way to handle this approach Let me know if you want to follow it and need code help:)

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I've changed it to List<int>

Comment: @PriyalPithadiya I have to add each value to a separate record. I can't have more than one value in a field.

Comment: Did it solve the issue?